# Using javascript and rails to make a drop down menu of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a drop down menu of links.  I use the following in rails to generate the drop down menu:

```
select("post","id", current_user.admin.post.all.collect {|p| [p.title, post_path(p) ] }, {:include_blank => 'None', :prompt => 'Your Posts'})
```

As a result of this ruby, the drop down menu looks like this:

```
<select id="post_id" name="post[id]">
  <option value="">Your posts</option>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="/posts/1">Vacations</option>
</select>
```

And I am trying to get the following javascript to send the user to the correct url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post_id").change(function () {
    var newwindow = $("#post_id option:selected").attr("id");
    window.location.replace(newwindow);
  })
});
```

However, it tries to go to /admins/undefined and comes back with this:

Couldn't find Admin with id=undefined

Any help would be appreciated!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because none of your `<option>` elements have `id` attributes, perhaps you want to look at their values:

```
$("#post_id").change(function () {
  var newwindow = $("#post_id option:selected").attr("value");
  if(newwindow)
      window.location.replace(newwindow);
  else
      // Complain or something.
});
```

Or just grab the value straight from the `<select>`:

```
$("#post_id").change(function () {
  var newwindow = $("#post_id").val();
  if(newwindow)
      window.location.replace(newwindow);
  else
      // Complain or something.
});
```

Comment: Doh!  Thanks! And too quick for me to even be able to accept the answer yet.  When it goes to the new page, my prompt of "Your Posts" does not show up on the drop down menu anymore.  Any idea why?

Comment: @John: Are you sure you're using the same `select` everywhere? Also, using both `:include_blank` and `:prompt` is a bit odd: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: Yeah, the select is in the layouts/application.html.haml file.  True about the :include_blank and :prompt . . . got rid of the :include_blank.

Comment: Yeah, the <select> is still there, but just missing the "Your Posts" option which goes with the :prompt

Comment: @John: I don't see why they wouldn't come out the same. You could try asking another question, that would give you more room to supply context and maybe someone will spot something that I'm not seeing.